# Linux for real time production server

Tags: centos, rhel, oracle-linux

I would like to know a linux OS for a real time 24x7 running production server. I have heard that RHEL is pretty stable & suitable for this type of usage.

Now I would like to know how it is different from CentOS & Oracle Linux ? Which one is better for a real time production server with cluster configuration ?

Comment: There are many stable distributions. Ubuntu, Debian,Suse and ofcourse the one you mentioned. What kind of difference you want to know.

Comment: I want to know which one can provide high availability without any crash or require reboot & of couse support for that distro.

Comment: This isn't "real time". Pleae be very careful of using that description when searching for a suitable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your choice of distribution really depends on what it will be used for, and who will be administering it.

RHEL and CentOS are both based on same core, however RHEL comes as a paid, supported, enterprise-level product. If you need the support of an SLA and the *amazing* team at Red Hat, that would certainly be a good option.

Personally, I am more familiar with Debian-based distros, so I tend to use Debian for my servers where reliability and security are key. That said, I have no need for an SLA, or to have engineers on-call.

(note, basically ALL Linux distributions are suitable for 24x7 operation. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by real-time, but I have plenty of Debian servers out there that operate 24x7 providing all business services)

EDIT:

In your comments, you asked for "high availability without any crash or require reboot".  When you have computing, you *always* have the possibility of a crash, and you *usually* will need to reboot at some point in time.

If you really need 99.999% uptime (you will not get a guarantee of 100% from any reputable provider), you're going to want a geographically-distributed cluster of servers... and again, most large Linux distros will be up to that task.  ;-)

Comment: I mean a linux server that is regularly capturing data from machines and saving in the database. The server should provide high availability & with out any crash or shutdown. So, it will also be used in cluster. In windows currently there is a problem of high PF usages in 3-4 months, so that it requires a reboot. It should happen with the distro.

Comment: Well, again, any of them should be able to do this. Any High Availability is largely going to depend on what software you select. HAProxy will give you high availability load balancing. MongoDB should give you high availability database. But no matter which Linux distro you choose, it will give similar reliability.

Comment: @Rhyven If your current problems are with Packet Filtering and having to reboot, even if there were problems with that on a Linux machine you would not have to reboot. Reboots are only necessary for kernel upgrades (and there are ways around that as well).

Comment: @Anthon - I think your comment was for @Rohan?  (also, I think by PF he meant "Page File" - maybe)

Comment: @Rhyven Yes it wasI probably typed @R and then hit return without really looking. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Rhyven, thanks for your response & the positive reply. PF is for Page File usages which creates problem in windows which requires reboot. Is there any similar problem like this in Linux also.